# Sending manually crafted UDP datagram in C?

Tags: c, ip

My professor instructed us to manually craft the UDP request and send it.
I have went so far to construct the UDP headers and content pointer.. the problem is `sendto` function requires data structure `sockaddr` and all what I have is string indicating the target ipv4..

So any idea how to convert this string to that structure or if there is a different send message ?

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void die (const char * format, ...)
{
    va_list vargs;
    va_start (vargs, format);
    vfprintf (stderr, format, vargs);
    fprintf (stderr, ".\n");
    exit (1);
}
void copy_lower_16_int(void * dest,int value)
{
    size_t sz  =sizeof(value);
    if(sz == 2)
        memcpy(dest,&value,2);
    else if (sz >2)
    {
        memcpy(dest,(&value)+sz-2,2);
    }
}
int sendTo(void * message,size_t size ,char * destinationIP,unsigned short  destinationPort)
{


    // Get the target transport protocol number
    const char* protocol_name="udp";
    struct protoent* protocol=getprotobyname(protocol_name);
    if (!protocol) {
        die("Protocol %s not found",protocol_name);
    }
    int protocol_number=protocol->p_proto;

    printf(" Protocol %s has number of %d \n",protocol_name,protocol_number);

    // Create raw socket for usage with IPv4 & the specified transport protocol (UDP)
    int fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,protocol_number);
    if (fd==-1) {
        die("Failed to create a raw socket, error : %s",strerror(errno));
    }

    // Construct the UDP datagram

    //Calculate total size ( message size + 8 byte for the headers)
    size_t total_size = size + 8;
    // Calculate the checksum 
    int checksum = 0x53AF;  

    void * content = (void*) malloc(total_size);
    const int sourcePort = 1524;


    copy_lower_16_int(content,sourcePort);
    copy_lower_16_int(content+2,destinationPort);
    copy_lower_16_int(content+4,total_size);

    copy_lower_16_int(content+6,checksum);


    memcpy(content+8,message,size);

}
void main(){
    printf("Size of int is %d",sizeof(2));
    sendTo("Cx",2,"127.0.0.1",5405);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you need to open a DGRAM_RAW socket, not DGRAM_UDP.  (Or something like that.)

Comment: I have totally raw socket.

Comment: Typically, you populate a sockaddr_in structure, then use its address in the sendto() call, casting its address to (struct sockaddr *)... e.g.  sendto(sockfd, buf, len, flags,
           ( struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr, sizeof(dest_addr));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by using `getaddrinfo` as the following

```
struct addrinfo *addr_result;
struct addrinfo hints;


memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;    /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_RAW; /* Datagram socket */
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;    /* For wildcard IP address */
hints.ai_protocol = protocol_number;          /* Any protocol */
hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
hints.ai_addr = NULL;
hints.ai_next = NULL;
getaddrinfo(destinationIP,NULL,&hints,&addr_result);

//Send the damn message
ssize_t sentsz = sendto(fd,content,total_size,0,addr_result->ai_addr,addr_result->ai_addrlen);
if (sentsz == -1)
{
        printf("It failed to send !!");
}
else {
        printf("It did send %d bytes",sentsz);
}
// free allocated memory

free(content);
freeaddrinfo(addr_result);
```